# Что чистит android при нехватке памяти?

Tags: java, android

В собственном классе храню статическое поле отдельно от класса для активити. Почему оно попадает под чистку?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а почему оно *не должно* попадать под чистку?

Comment: Без понятия, я новичок и поэтому интересуюсь. Я лишь знаю, что он активити точно чистит.

Comment: слишком мало информации, покажите код, в какой момент вы уверены, что поле очищается, и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нехватке памяти андройд сначала выгружает фоновые (не видимые пользователю) активи, затем если памяти ещё не хватает начинает выгружать фоновые сервисы не прикрепленные к видимым активити. На любом этапе чистки если у приложения не осталось активити и сервисов, то выгружено будет всё приложение, включая и все его статические поля разумеется.